# check if numeric element is in an interval key dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, intervals

from the following dictionary with `tuple` as keys and a `string` as value:

```
dict_interval = {(1,5):"foo",(5,100):"bar"}
```

by using the dict, how would be possible to use a function with the following behaviour?

```
age = 4    
categorizer(age, dict_interval)
```

gives the following output:

```
"foo"
```

Comment: What is the max value of the intervals? Does it have to be a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect age to be within **multiple intervals** and you want to get them all:

```
# Categoriser, returns a list
def categoriser(age, d) -> list:
    return [value for key, value in d.items() 
            if is_between(age, key)]

# Helper function
def is_between(value, interval):
    return interval[0] <= value < interval[1]
```

I have added an overlapping interval to your data

```
>>> dict_interval = {(1,5): "foo", (2, 5): "foo2", (5,100): "bar"}
>>> categoriser(4, dict_interval)
["foo", "foo2"]
```

If you want the **first value only**:

```
# Categoriser, returns first value 
def categoriser(age, d) -> str:
    for key, value in d.items():
        if is_between(age, key):
            return value
```

```
>>> categoriser(4, dict_interval)
"foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def categorizer(value, dict_interval):
    for k in dict_interval:
        if k[0] < value < k[1]:
            return(dict_interval[k])
```

This should work, assuming that key is unique I guess.

Comment: You don't need a `break` after a `return`

Comment: Thankyou for your specification, it was a dumb mistake indeed!

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the values where the age is in the interval you can use the following code:

```
def get_all_values(age):
   res = []
   for key, value in dict_interval .items():
      if (age >= key[0] and age <= key[1]):
         res.append(value)
   return res
```

this function will return a list of all the correct values. If you can only get 1 correct value you can do it like that:

```
def get_value(age):
   for key in dict_interval .keys():
      if (age >= key[0] and age <= key[1]):
         return dict_interval[key]
```

Comment: As a side note, if the intervals were consecutive and not overlapping then it would be possible to check for `age <= key[1]` only, which would speed up things 2x. At this point the `dict` key could even be the upper limit alone, instead of the (lower,upper) `tuple`

Comment: It would work if the intervals are in order